# Study of algebraic structures analogous to the ring of smooth functions and module of vector fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, smooth-manifolds

$\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}$

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. $\Ga(TM)$ is a module over the ring of smooth (real) functions (which is also an algebra, and denoted by $C^{\infty}(M)$).

Also, each $X \in \Ga(TM)$ defines a [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28differential_algebra%29) on $C^{\infty}(M)$.

That is , we have two operations:

$(1)$ "scalar multiplication" (satisfies the module axioms):

$C^{\infty}(M) \times \Ga(TM) \to \Ga(TM) \, , (f,X) \mapsto fX$,

$(2)$ "differentiation":

$\Ga(TM) \times C^{\infty}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M) \, , (X,f) \mapsto Xf$

satisfying:

$(1) \, (X+Y)f=Xf+Yf$

$(2) \, (gX)f=g(Xf)$

$(3) \, X(fg)=g(Xf)+f(gX)$ (derivation property)

---

Is there any literature from an algebraic perspective, on this situation; i.e on pairs $(M,R)$ where $M$ is an $R$-module , and we also have a "differentiation" operation:

$M \times R \to R \, , (m,r) \mapsto mr$, satisfying:

$(1)$ $(m+m')r=mr+m'r$

$(2)$ $(r'm)r=r'(mr)$

$(3)$ $m(rr')=r(mr')+r'(mr)$

Can we say anything interesting on this interplay algebraically? Has this phenomena been studied from this point of view?

Comment: Your differentiation operation is just a morphism $M \to \text{Der}(R)$ of $R$-modules, where $\text{Der}(R)$ denotes the Lie algebra of derivations on $R$.

Comment: And in any case vector fields are already themselves quite close to just being the Lie algebra of derivations on $C^{\infty}(M)$, although some tweaks are necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you have much more structure than this; most importantly, vector fields also have a Lie bracket, and the Lie derivative gives an action of the corresponding Lie algebra. One way to package up all of this structure is to talk about a [Gerstenhaber algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerstenhaber_algebra) structure on polyvector fields (sections of exterior powers of the tangent bundle).

Polyvector fields have a multiplication, but they also have a Lie bracket of degree $-1$ called the [Schouten-Nijenhuis bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schouten%E2%80%93Nijenhuis_bracket) which reproduces both the Lie derivative and the Lie bracket of vector fields. The interaction between these is a version of the same interaction for a [Poisson algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_algebra) except that there are a lot of signs.